# ASP NET MVC ActionLink html entity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Хочется, чтобы ссылка отображалась, как и ручная верстка.
Сначала результирующий код:

```html
<a class="btn btn-default" href="/Account/Register">Регистрация</a>
```

Код во вьюшке

```
@Html.ActionLink("Регистрация &radio;","Register","Account",null,new {@class="btn btn-lg btn-default"})
```

А хотелось бы

```html
<a class="btn btn-default" href="/Account/Register">Регистрация &radio;</a>
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нету разницы для этих записей:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="/Account/Register/">Регистрация &radio;</a>

@Html.ActionLink("Регистрация &radio;","Register","Account",null,new {@class="btn btn-lg btn-default"})

<a class="btn btn-default" href="@Url.Action("Register", "Account")">Регистрация &raquo;</a>
```

они будут одинакова работать.

Comment: Веб-приложение не всегда в корень установлено!

Comment: да ты прав  Pavel Mayorov

Comment: @EmirMamashov мало того что не всегда в корень, так еще и во второй строчке текст ссылки будет кривой

Answer (score 1):

Можно например так:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="@Url.Action("Register", "Account")">Регистрация &raquo;</a>
```

поменяйте у себя в коде `&radio;` на `&raquo;`
и используйте `Url.Action` для генерации URL

Comment: Да похоже это лучший вариант спасибо.

Comment: @VladimirKorotenko а жмякнуть галочку мне в карму? ;)